# How to add new record fields in data storage after contract deployment? Is storing JSON in a field viable?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, storage, json

AFAIK, there is no way to update storage types(ex: can't add a new record field to a Map<sp.Nat, sp.record(a=1)>) of a contract after deployment. (Correct me if I'm wrong). This means, after a contract is deployed later on, the only way to add additional storage is to rely on encoding the data in JSON or to have it live under a different contract. Are there any other alternatives?

Is the main downside to using JSON for storage the expense in parsing/unparsing and saving/resaving of the JSON string blob? Perhaps if the JSON blob isn't too big it's not a big deal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing and unparsing json seems totally impractical.

You’re correct in your assumption. You cannot change the type of the storage. You could use a map so that fields are replaced by keys (supposing you want to add a field of a known type).

Comment: that's a good point. using several maps to handle various known types would work and is way better than JSON

Comment: An alternative is to have a map whose values are a variant type with the different possibilities. See the Chainlink oracle template for an example. Please let me say that simplicity is an important factor anyhow; you should not over engineer your design.