# How to migrate existing smart contract data to a new one when needing additional storage requirements?

Tags: smart-contracts, storage, upgrade

Obviously the first answer is to try to avoid running into this scenario by having some flexibility in storing additional fields using maps ([example](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/3346/5904)). However, let's think about the scenario where this wasn't done.

Say you need additional storage for something and that wasn't built into the original contract and upgrading the contract [using lambdas or a delegate](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/613/how-to-upgrade-a-smart-contract) isn't possible because the new storage fields need to be under a specific contract.

How would a migration for the existing data look like? Is it feasible to this without giving the admin developer too much power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

[image]

Or just store upgradable structures as bytes and lambdas to unpack/pack and process those bytes. (Expensive and doesn't work with big maps)

> Is it feasible to this without giving the admin developer too much
> power?

No, having an upgradable contract means that the contract can change its behavior to do unintended things. But you could have a multisig admin when multiple entities are involved.